# Arithmetic binary operators -gt, -lt give error but work in a shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I wrote this simple script it works too but shows an error

```
clear
echo Enter 1st number
read n1
echo Enter 2nd number
read n2
echo MUlti is `expr $n1 \* $n2`;
if [$n1 -lt $n2]
then
 echo $n1 'is bigger than' $n2
else
 echo $n2 'is bigger than' $n1
fi
```

#### output

```
Enter 1st number
5
Enter 2nd number
10
MUlti is 50
./script.sh: line 7: [5: command not found
10 is bigger than 5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `[` is a command builtin, also known as `test`, and as all commands requires at least a space to separate it from other words in the command. `[` is also available as a regular command in `/usr/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/test`.

The presence of a final `]` is instead a requirement of the command, when invoked as `[`, and the spaces around it are required as for every parameter of a command.

That said, in bash you should use the command `[[`, that has some avantages over `[`, like for example supporting `&&` and `||` for logical operations, beside `-a` and `-o`.

Moreover, to do integer arithmetic operations and comparison between integers it is better to use arithmetic expansions `$((math operations))`, and the corresponding command `((math ops))`.

With these observations, your script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo "Enter 1st number"
read n1
echo "Enter 2nd number"
read n2
echo "Multi is $((n1 * n2))"
if ((n1 > n2)); then
  echo "$n1 is bigger than $n2"
else
  echo "$n2 is bigger than $n1"
fi
```

Remember to make it executable (`chmod +x my-script`), then execute it with `./my-script`.

Comment: Just curious, is there any necessity besides convenience to make a script executable rather than calling `bash script.sh`? As I understand it, they both translate to the same actions on the part of the shell, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @root45: there is no difference that I know of. Also, the latter works also if `script.sh` is not marked as executable. But the user should not know how the developer write the application, he should just call it by name. In `/usr/bin` there are ELF binaries, perl, python, sh, bash scripts and also other type of applications.

Answer (score 5):

For bash conditional if statements, you need to have a whitespace right before and right after your condition. Yours should look like:

```
if [ $n1 -lt $n2 ]
```

instead of

```
if [$n1 -lt $n2]
```

Goofy, but that's the bash shell.