# Is it possible to provide "if" and "else" syntaxis in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I was asked to create command which generates one word in terminal, if internet connection is absense, and another one, if it present. For doing that it seems that I need "if" and "else" syntaxis. Is it possible to provide such syntaxis in terminal?

Comment: Or see http://askubuntu.com/questions/58385/help-on-if-else-in-shell, and http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: @muru : I'm the newbie in Ubuntu, and I think that the bash is something different than terminal. My question is about terminal.

Comment: Your terminal runs bash. See http://askubuntu.com/q/506510/158442 and http://askubuntu.com/q/111144/158442

Comment: @JohnTaylor ok, but the terminal understands bash ;-)

Comment: Bash essentially is the command prompt that runs in the terminal. You better start learning bash scripting cuz that's what you essentially want

Comment: @JohnTaylor, there is a fundamental difference between a [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) and a [shell (or command-line interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). You should learn about them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ if [ 'a' = 'b' ]; then echo 'Equal'; else echo 'Not equal'; fi
Not equal
$
```